# get contents in a span id using regex help

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the value inside a span id or div id. For example from 
`<span id="lastPrice">29.00</span>`
i want to get the 29.00. please help.

Comment: Use PHP DOM, not Regex. It's less likely to break horribly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this through `regexp` that badly.

```
$string = "<span id=\"lastPrice\">29.00</span>";
preg_match("/\<span id\=\"lastPrice\"\>([\d.]+?)\<\/span\>/",$string,$match);
print "<pre>"; var_dump($match[1]); print "</pre>";
```

But there are far more better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at XPath => [PHP - Searching and filtering with XPath](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/12/3/3)

> [...] XPath is a darn sight easier than regular expressions for basic usage. That said, it might take a little while to get your head around all the possibilities it opens up to you!

Google will give u plenty of examples and tutorials.